# Add password to an existing zip file

Tags: files, zip

is there a way to add a password to an existing .zip file in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 35):

To encrypt a zip file after it has been created, you can use `zipcloak`

The syntax is:

```
zipcloak foo.zip
```

You will be prompted to give the password for the zip file called *foo.zip*

You can zip a file(s) in creating a zip file using the `-e` parameter i.e.

```
zip -e foo.zip file1
```

Comment: Damn, didn't even know that was already installed on my system. Both Ubuntu and on macOS. Nice one!